# How to connect to postgresql locally with node.js on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: node.js, linux, postgresql, database-connection, ubuntu-16.04

Soo I am using Digitalocean droplet and used this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-16-04 to set it up. The postgres works on the machine when I connect using my user.

When I try to connect to the postgres database using node.js it doesn't work.

```
var pg = require('pg');
var conString = "postgres://myuser:password@localhost:5432/dbname";

var client = new pg.Client(conString);
client.connect();
```

When I look at the node.js error logs it says that

```
error: password authentication failed for user "myuser"
    at Connection.parseE (/usr/lib/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:572:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (/usr/lib/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:396:$
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:132:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:547:20)
```

I'm not sure what password it is meaning. The only password I have entered is the one I used to create myuser on Ubuntu just like the tutorial instructed. I'm sure that the password matches the one I entered for myuser. I also tried to leave it blank but that's not working either.

But I assume the connection works, and only the authentication fails? Is there some default password for new postgres databases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I found a way

```
$ sudo -u myuser psql myuser
postgres=# \password myuser
```

Then it asked for my password I entered the same password as in the connection string and now it works, weird.